# (Probably) A Simple Command - Excel

Tags: excel

I just joined recently and am really excited to dive into the world of programming.  There is still a ton of stuff I don't know, but I'm very proud of myself because I feel like I'm making headway into programming, whereas I used to have a mental block before.  I've always been an infrastructure type of gal.  But anyway --

I am creating an excel spreadsheet for my new budget.  Here is a screencap of my problem (According to rules, new user can't attach images):

http://i66.tinypic.com/hx53zm.png

So this is what I want it to do, logically speaking:  Stay blank (B38) until something is entered.  Do (B7-B14-B36) if all the fields have something in them.  Otherwise, just subtract whatever's in either B14 and/or B36 from B7.

I'm sure it's really simple -- I just lack the knowledge since I'm new.  I have been playing around with this for a few days and searching on Google, and I can't figure out how to make it work for my spreadsheet.  I have tried the CountA, Count, If, Isblank statements... and just can't get it to go.

This isn't really important to anything in my life, it's just something I'm making for myself to keep my financials in order -- AND to give me practice with some coding.

Thank you for any help you can give me!

Chris

Comment: Did that work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you will want to add the following to B38

```
=IF(B7 <> ""; B7-B14-B36; "")
```

Depending on your version of Excel, you may need to replace the ; with ,